# Downloading a file from S3 to local machine using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to use a Python script to automate downloading a file from AWS S3 to my local machine. The Python script itself is hosted on Ubuntu (AWS EC2 instance), so it's not recognizing a directory on my local machine.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
print("this script downloads the file from s3 to local machine")

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

BUCKET_NAME = 'sfbucket.myBucket'
KEY = 'sf_events.json'

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, '/Users/Documents/my_file.json')

print('end')
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Documents/my_file.json.CDC5FEf4'

What am I doing wrong?  If I replace the output directory to `/home/ubuntu/` it works fine, but I want the file on my local machine.

Comment: Do you run this code on your local machine that has the path `/Users/Documents`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you saying the code should be: s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, '/Users/Documents/  ?

Comment: Where so you run this entire python script? If it works with `/home/ubuntu` it means a linux machine but the path that does not exist is Windows one

Comment: correct - i'm running it with ubuntu (linux)

Comment: edited question to reflect this.

Comment: Ununtu does not have the path `/User/Documents` which what the error indicates

Comment: So I do access the local path ?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script has to run on your local Windows machine *not* on EC2 instance.

Alternatively, you can simply use aws cli

`aws s3 cp s3://sfbucket.myBucket/sf_events.json /Users/Documents/my_file.json`

Comment: iTech - thanks, but I have this all set up to run python code from an EC2 instance and then use crontab to schedule jobs.  I'd like to be able to do this in a python script that is hosted on EC2 instance.  It looks like you've provided a solution in command line above, do you have a solution that would work to be run from a python script on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Both the script and the command will have the same result, running them on the EC2 instance will download the file to the EC2 instance.

Comment: If you want your file on your local machine eithet copy it from the EC2 instance or run the command/script on the local Windows machine. No other solutions possible.

Comment: Do I use boto3 to copy it from the EC2 instance ?  Where can i find documentation on this?

Comment: You can copy with `scp` if you have `ssh` access from your local machine to the EC2 instance. Honestly, the simplest way is to run the command or script directly on your local machine.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I've got boto3 installed on EC2 instance, but not locally.  Would I need to re-install all dependencies on my local machine?

Comment: Yes if you decide to use the script. Otherwise just install aws cli and use the command I shared in my answer, much simpler and more reliable.

Comment: Could I run that command you provided on crontab?  I ran the command on my local machine, and it seems there might be an issue with credentials.. it says: fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

Comment: Yes, you can run it on your local machine with crobtab. You need to do first `aws configure` to enter your AWS access keys

Comment: thank you iTech!  It's working now.  I'm able to copy the file to my local machine using that command.  I'll have to research how to run that command on crontab now.  I was hoping to avoid running any script on my local machine.. I'm surprised this isn't easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to download the file using the EC2 instance, this machine doesn't know your local path `/Users/Documents/my_file.json`

You have two options:

1. Run this script directly in your local machine.
   In this case, you have to run this script in your local machine and make sure you have access to this bucket.
2. Run this script in EC2 Instance and copy.
   In this case, you have to download the file to somewhere `/home/ubuntu/` and then after in your local machine make a copy from EC2.
   You can use [SCP][1]

You can install the SCP server in your local machine but the problem is that your local machine probably doesn't have a private IP, so every time that your local IP change you have to update the script. Maybe you should think about to do whatever you need to do with this file directly on EC2 Instance or if it's a real manual thing, sending via email, maybe?

Comment: Erik - thanks.  The whole goal here is to be able to run everything from the cloud; I'm using this python script on the EC2 instance, and scheduling it to run once a day with crontab.  Ideally, I'd like to find some way to output the file from s3 to my local machine without having to run the python script locally.

Comment: The big problem here is because usually, Local Machines don't have a private IP.
If your local machine has, you could install SCP server in your local machine and then automate the script to run a SCP command to send the file to your local machine.